# How can I convert cell content in EXCEL to HTML code?

Tags: excel, cell

Basically I want to create macro to get cell content and put in HTML paragraph tag, but if cell contains new line symbol to put new line in new tag. Can someone help me to do it or provide it to me? Thanks in advance.

Incorrect:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>1
       2
       3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Correct:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

```
Sub lf2html()

Dim i, chrCount As Integer
Dim htmlTxt As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim SetCellStart
Dim SetCellStop

SetCellStart = InputBox("StartCell ( f0r example: a1 ):", "Enter number!")
SetCellStop = InputBox("StopCell ( f0r example: a2 )", "Enter number!")

'MsgBox SetCellStart SetCellStop
For Each cell In Range(SetCellStart, SetCellStop)
    htmlTxt = "<html><head></head><body><p>"
        chrCount = cell.Characters.Count

        For i = 1 To chrCount
            With cell.Characters(i, 1)
                If (Asc(.Text) = 10) Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</p><p>"
                Else
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & .Text
                End If
            End With
        Next

    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</p></body></html>"
    cell.Value = htmlTxt
Next cell

End Sub
```